# Adding multiple constraints at once in Xcode 7

Tags: storyboard, constraints, xcode7, shift

In previous versions of Xcode you could drag from one UI element in your storyboard to another and by holding the *Shift* button pressed, you could add more constraints between those two components - all at once. In Xcode 7 this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to add multiple constraints at once in Xcode 7?

Comment: Can you please specify some of the constraints that you would like to add between two elements by drag and drop?

Comment: Leading, top, trailing and bottom space for example. Before Xcode you could add all these constraints at once by pushing and holding the shift button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's the same, but now you must press "Add Constraints" in the same menu.

[image]
[image]

When adding constraints, first thing you see at the bottom is "Hold Shift to select multiple". If you hold *Shift* and select your first constraint, this line changes into a button that says "Add Constraints". 
Until Xcode 6 you didn't need to press the "Add Constraints" button, as they were added automatically once you would release the *Shift* button. In Xcode 7 you need to press "Add Constraints" before you leave this dialogue window.